# SVN is losing my file permissions

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I created a new repository and IMPORTED in a project (a web site - so file permissions are quite important).

When I checked out the project, I noticed that my carefully set (ugo) permissions on individual folders had been lost and all folders were assigned u:g to me.

Is this default behavior of SVN - if so, how may I get SVN to store the permissions I have set at folder/file level?

I am running Ubuntu 10.0.4

Comment: @EmCo: No, I am using the command line binaries (i.e. svnadmin svn etc)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149/storing-file-permissions-in-subversion-repository -- nothing changed since that time.

Comment: Can anyone recommend a versioning system that STORES file permissions?

Answer (score 0):

SVN does not keep file permissions.

To go around this you can use:

`getfacl -R dirname > filname.perm` <- Backup

And to restore use:

`setfacl --restore=filname.perm` <- Restore