# How to set "execute" attribute to a file and check it in SVN from Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, svn, bamboo, file-attributes

I have SVN configured in Linux at a different location and I need to check-in a shell script to SVN with executable attribute ON from Windows. I use Bamboo as CI, which checks out sources from SVN and does the periodic build. It throws error that shell script is not executable. (Bamboo run as root).

What is the best way to set the executable permission?

I don't use any SVN client and use eclipse to check-in and check-out. If SVN client is the only, how do I find a version that is compatible with SVN plugin that I use in eclipse.
I had a compatibility problem earlier. When I checked-in a file from Tortoise, I couldn't checkout that file from Eclipse.

Comment: Does anything from this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149/storing-file-permissions-in-subversion-repository

Comment: I don't see why this has so many close votes for "of topic" as SVN is clearly a programing tool.

Comment: Thanks phasetwenty, it does help to understand the problem clearly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

SVN ignores UNIX file permissions when commiting. The way that you set exec permissions on a file is to change the svn properties for that file. If you are on Windows, the easy way to do this is to install Tortoise SVN. Then after you have committed, use Tortoise to open the repo-browser. Find a file that needs to be executable and right-click it to open properties.

The dialog that appears is the SVN properties dialog. Click New to add a new property, select svn:executable from the dropdown list, and set the property value to *.

That's it. When you click OK, it is committed to the SVN repo. The next time you, or the build machine, do an `svn update`, that file will have executable permissions on Unix/Linux.

Comment: Thanks Michael, its working. Same process I did last time but change the attribute and then checked it in with Tortoise client, so I had a compatibility issue.

Comment: Michael, I believe your first sentence, "SVN ignores UNIX file permissions when commiting" should be "SVN ignores changes in UNIX file permissions once a file has been added."

Answer (score 53):

`svn propset svn:executable "*" someScript`

The syntax is `propset key value` so `svn:executable` is the key and `"*"` is the value

`someScript` is the filename

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it is useful to those of us not using windows.