# Does SVN keep track of file ownership and permissions?

Tags: svn, permissions, file-ownership

If I check out a file via SVN and change the permissions and/or owner of the file in my working directory, will those changes be reflected when I commit the file?

If so, how can I prevent this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing file permissions in Subversion repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149/storing-file-permissions-in-subversion-repository)

Comment: I would think this would be pretty simple to test yourself...

Answer (score 1):

If you just change permissions or ownership nothing will happen on commit. Svn only detects changes to svn properties or data. There are some special [properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.ref) which allow some minimal control. But you want to avoid any impact if I understood, so having no impact from local permissions changes is working out of the box...