# Linux permissions on files checked out from SVN

Tags: linux, file-permissions

The server we use is configured to not run PHP scripts if the file is group writable.  We use SVN to deploy projects on the server (essentially they are working copies we never make changes to or commit from).  The release versions are copied to tags and then on the server we svn switch to the new tag.

This used to work great, but for one of our projects whenever we svn switch to a new version, the files are set to -rw-rw-r--.  So after each deployment we need to manually do a "chmod -R g-w ./".

Any idea why this is happening and how to make SVN write files with the desired permissions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing file permissions in Subversion repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149/storing-file-permissions-in-subversion-repository)

Comment: Did you check/alter the `umask` of the user running the `svn switch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had nothing to do with SVN, but with default permissions.  It appears the way to set the default permissions new files created is to do:

setfacl -d -m g::r ./

The -d flag changes the default permissions.  -m modifies them and g::r means set only r for g.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion does not manage or manipulate permissions other than the executable (and that only if you set `svn:executable`). If you need to change permissions on your working copy, write a wrapper script for your checkout to make those changes after the checkout/update.

Comment: Is there anything in the parent directories / user settings / system settings (or anywhere else) that defines what default permissions a newly created file gets if nothing is specified?

If I do something like ls > foo.bar that gets created with ug=rw as well.

Comment: That's a UNIX/Linux usage/administration question at its core and not Subversion, but research `umask`.